# How do I give an R variable a name from C code

Tags: r

Does anyone know how to programatically assign a value to a "named" value in R internals, (e.g. 'x')

My application has calculated a value (in this case `x`) and I want to pass this variable into an R script (which is run via R_eval), however I don't know how to tell R that data is 'x'

```
SEXP data
Rf_protect(data = Rf_allocVector(REALSXP, 1)));
double dval = 5.0
REAL(data)[j] = dval;

// I thought I might have to assign an attribute but this doesn't seem to work.
// Rf_setAttrib(data, R_NameSymbol, Rf_mkChar("x"));

//code will then run supplied script which will use x but won't define it

y <- c(1,2,3,x)

summary(c)
```

At present I am getting an parse error of `'object 'x' not found'`

Many thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0):

So on further digging it seems its possible to achieve what I wanted by doing the following.

```
SEXP variableName= Rf_install(const_cast<char*>("x"));
Rf_defineVar(variableName, data, _R_GlobalEnv);
```